# UIButton in another view is not being called

Tags: objective-c

I have this very simple UIButton that usually works , but now i have him in another class of kind UIVIEW , as some menu. In the main view of the app, when i am adding this menu view class- which has that button , the button is not fire the method . why is that ?
Is this has to do with the button delegate that the main view does not see ?

```
UIButton *exit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[exit addTarget:self action:@selector(exit:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
exit.frame=  CGRectMake(0,frame.size.height,50,50) ;
[exit setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[exit setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[exit setBackgroundColor:thisColor];
 //exit.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
 exit.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-thin" size:32];
[back addSubview:exit];
```

**EDIT:**

To add this class to the main view i do :

```
MainMenuView *MM=[[MainMenuView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
 MM.tag=1004;
[self.view addSubview: MM];
```

Comment: `fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-thin`, `thin` should be uppercase `Thin`, for the records ;) Moreover, don't you get an error for `frame.size.height`?

Comment: What is `back`? Is property `userInteractionEnabled` equal to `YES` for it?

Comment: back is a UIView and yes interactions are enabled at it . and font- thin also works .

Comment: by the way , adding it just to that view ( its a class of uiview, that has inside it another UIView-back , and the button added to 'back' , and also i have tried adding it to self, both did not worked. this view also has scrollview that does works .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved.

So , the UIView that i created has its frame, and because its a menu , its frame is not the full screen size, so :

```
   back=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-frame.size.height, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
```

This view ends at some point, and the button i have added is under that rect for this view, hence is not clickable .